# How to document a Python variable?

Tags: python, documentation

How can I document a variable in Python. In JavaScript / JSDoc I can do something like that.:

```
/** @type {Array<Number>} */
var foo;
/** @type {Number[]} */
var bar;
```

Some IDEs than can give better code completion.

Is this also possible in Python?

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#type-comments ... for questions like this first google "pep8" and your question... you will find the reference in the python style guide

Comment: its probably important to note that for the most part the type is unenforced... and of coarse whether you get any typehinting or help depends on the IDE you are using

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work, but I have to write `# type: list[int]` instead of `# type: List[int]`. Is that correct? It also seems that PyCharm supports it.

Comment: `x, y, z = [], [], []  # type: (List[int], List[int], List[str])` is how it is defined in the spec ... your particular IDE may not implement it in this way ...

Comment: Ah okay, please answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x, y, z = [], [], [] # type: (List[int], List[int], List[str])` is how it is defined in the spec ... your particular IDE may or may not implement it in this way ...

see also: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#type-comments